# Python Web scraping - Find models of a special brand in www.truecar.com

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape a special data in python with bs4 library.

https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/suzuki/location-chicago-il/

I want to scrape model names of a special brand (for example Suzuki).
when we open inspect element in web page and pick "model" element. At last, we got this lines:

```
<option selected="" value="">All</option>

<option value="aerio">Aerio</option>

<option value="equator">Equator</option>

<option value="esteem">Esteem</option>

<option value="forenza">Forenza</option>

<option value="grand-vitara">Grand Vitara</option>

<option value="kizashi">Kizashi</option>

<option value="reno">Reno</option>

<option value="sx4">SX4</option>
```

etc.
so based on what I have learned, I write this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


respose = requests.get('https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/suzuki/location-chicago-il/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(respose.text , 'html.parser')

models = soup.find_all('select',attrs={"class":"form-control-select-md form-select-element",
                                       "data-test":"searchFiltersModel"})
```

but in models variable, we just have following text:

```
<select aria-label="Change vehicle model" class="form-control-select-md form-select-element" data-test="searchFiltersModel" data-qa="ModelFilter">
<option selected="" value="">All</option>
</select>
```

why this happened and what is the solution?

Comment: The problem is that the list of models isn't populated unless and until you select certain search criteria (e.g. price range).

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the car models are rendered after you select the make. Going to just the static url will not render that. A better option here is to use the api.

Note I used a package `choice` here to get the slug needed to input into the payload:

```
import requests

#pip install choice  <--- TO INSTALL CHOICE
import choice

url = 'https://www.truecar.com/abp/api/vehicles/used/listings/aggregations_challenger?new_or_used=u'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

makes = jsonData['makes']
makes_dict = {}
for each in makes:
    makes_dict[each['name']] = each['slug'] 

make_key = choice.Menu(makes_dict.keys()).ask()
make_slug = makes_dict[make_key]

url = 'https://www.truecar.com/abp/api/vehicles/used/listings/aggregations_challenger'

payload = {'make_slug': make_slug}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

for each in jsonData['makes']:
    if each['name'] == make_key:
        models = [x['name'] for x in each['models']]
        break

print(models)
```

**Output:**

```
 0: Saturn
 1: Scion
 2: smart
 3: Subaru
 4: Suzuki
 5: Tesla
 6: Toyota
 7: Volkswagen
 8: Volvo

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 4

['Aerio', 'Equator', 'Esteem', 'Forenza', 'Grand Vitara', 'Kizashi', 'Reno', 'SX4', 'Verona', 'Vitara', 'X-90', 'XL7']
```

If you want to get all of them on one go, just iterate through the make_slugs:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.truecar.com/abp/api/vehicles/used/listings/aggregations_challenger'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

makes = jsonData['makes']
makes_dict = {}
for each in makes:
    makes_dict[each['name']] = each['slug'] 


for k,v in makes_dict.items():
    payload = {'make_slug': v}
    jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

    for each in jsonData['makes']:
        if each['name'] == k:
            models = [x['name'] for x in each['models']]
            break
    
    print(k,': ',models)
```

**Output:**

```
Acura :  ['CL', 'ILX', 'Integra', 'MDX', 'NSX', 'RDX', 'RL', 'RLX', 'RSX', 'TL', 'TLX', 'TSX', 'ZDX']
Alfa Romeo :  ['4C', 'Giulia', 'Stelvio']
AM General :  ['Hummer']
Aston Martin :  ['DB11', 'DB7 Vantage', 'DB9', 'DBS', 'DBX', 'Rapide', 'Rapide S', 'V8 Vantage', 'Vanquish', 'Vanquish S', 'Vantage', 'Virage']
Audi :  ['A3', 'A4', 'A4 allroad', 'A5', 'A6', 'A6 allroad', 'A7', 'A8', 'allroad', 'e-tron', 'e-tron GT', 'Q3', 'Q5', 'Q7', 'Q8', 'R8', 'RS 3', 'RS 4', 'RS 5', 'RS 6 Avant', 'RS 7', 'RS Q8', 'RS6', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'SQ5', 'SQ7', 'SQ8', 'TT', 'TT RS', 'TTS']
Bentley :  ['Arnage', 'Azure', 'Bentayga', 'Continental', 'Continental GT', 'Continental Supersports', 'Flying Spur', 'Mulsanne']
BMW :  ['1 Series', '1 Series M', '2 Series', '3 Series', '4 Series', '5 Series', '6 Series', '7 Series', '8 Series', 'i3', 'i8', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M6', 'M8', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X3 M', 'X4', 'X4 M', 'X5', 'X5 M', 'X6', 'X6 M', 'X7', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z8']
Buick :  ['Cascada', 'Century', 'Enclave', 'Encore', 'Encore GX', 'Envision', 'LaCrosse', 'LeSabre', 'Lucerne', 'Park Avenue', 'Rainier', 'Regal', 'Regal Sportback', 'Regal TourX', 'Rendezvous', 'Terraza', 'Verano']
Cadillac :  ['ATS', 'ATS-V', 'Catera', 'CT4', 'CT5', 'CT6', 'CT6-V', 'CTS', 'CTS-V', 'DeVille', 'DeVille Professional', 'Deville Professional', 'DTS', 'DTS Professional', 'Eldorado', 'ELR', 'Escalade', 'Escalade EXT', 'Seville', 'SRX', 'STS', 'STS-V', 'XLR', 'XLR-V', 'XT4', 'XT5', 'XT6', 'XTS']
...
```

Comment: I don't want brands name. I have them. I scrape brands from https://www.truecar.com/shop/used/?filterType=brand . now; I want models of each brand. do you know a way for solve this?

Comment: Did you try or read my solution? It gives the the models. BUT inorder to get the model names, you need to pass in the make. If you have a list of the `make_slug`, then you can iterate through those.

Comment: I added an additional code there to get all the make/models